In Micronaut Data, for JDBC, getting an error " No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository."
I'm using Postgres as the underlying DB. I've declared my repository like this, included the correct dependencies, setup the data class (I'm using Kotlin 1.9), I'm running Micronaut 4.2.3
@Repository
abstract class KeyValueRepository : GenericRepository<KeyValue, Long> {
    abstract fun findByKey(key: String): KeyValue?
    abstract fun save(keyValue: KeyValue): KeyValue
}

And the error I get when trying to run any function is this:
ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
...
io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2735)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:856)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:848)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.operations.DefaultRepositoryOperationsRegistry.provide(DefaultRepositoryOperationsRegistry.java:53)
    ... 80 common frames omitted

I've included all the right dependencies (I've triple checked), rebuilt the app, tried running in different configurations, it always comes back to this.

please add your pom.xml or build.gradle. Otherwise it’s wild guessing
